# Monitoring request duration on azure aks

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I'm working on a project hosted on Azure using AKS. I was asked to monitor the performance of some requests. I remember I could use Application Insights to see requested URLs and their duration when hosting an application in Azure AppService.

Is there something similar for AKS? I'd like to see the URLs I'm hitting and the completion times of those requests.

Comment: In AppService there are two ways to enable Application Insights - as extension or directly in code. The latter approach works for any platform, including AKS. So, you can instrument your app with Application Insights SDK, deploy to AKS and it will collect requests, dependencies, exceptions, etc.

Comment: Have you seen either [jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.19/) or [zipkin](https://zipkin.io/)?  If I understand correctly that's exactly what you're looking for. Let me know if that suits you.

Comment: Thanks a lot ZakiMa, sorry for my late response. But you're answer fits perfectly for the problem that I was having.

Comment: @ZakiMa is using SDK the only way, still in 2022?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Adding to @ZakiMa's comment above, [codeless instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview) of Azure Kubernetes Service is currently available for only for Java applications through the standalone agent. To monitor applications in other languages use the [SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/kubernetes-codeless#other-languages).